# Bringing the previous period

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate annual change rate by using same table.
For example ;

```
     T          Value 
     31.12.2019 30
     31.12.2018 45
     31.12.2017 20
     31.12.2016 36
```

(T - T-1 ) / T-1 . For 2018 = (45 -20) / 20

I have customer ıd, terms, value in my table.

Comment: I'm confused.  What does your table really look like?  What results do you want?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I m using oracle, there must be change rates on a period basis. how can ı show my table, there are customer ıd, terms, values.

Comment: . . You show a table, but it doesn't have those columns.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly :

```
select * ,(Value - PrvValue) / PrvValue as changeRate
( 
  select * , LAG(Value,1,Value) over (order by T))  PrvValue 
  from yourtable
) tt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the "previous" and "current" VALUEs in a CTE, then use them in the main query:

```
WITH cteSome_table
  AS (SELECT T,
             VALUE,
             LAG(VALUE, 1, VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY T) AS PREV_VALUE
        FROM SOME_TABLE)
SELECT T,
       (VALUE - PREV_VALUE) / PREV_VALUE
  FROM cteSome_table
  ORDER BY T
```

I think this is a bit easier to read and understand.